# Broadcasting a keras model with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, keras

I have a Keras model and I need to broadcast it/include it in a pyspark UDF. It can't be pickled,  so simply sc.broadcast(model) won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: that method works and I get the import keras part working, but it then fails when asking for tensorflow. Following the same idea for tensorflow and sending a .zip file, I get
`ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.` I assume my tensorflow is built on a different OS than the worker...? any idea?

Comment: The redirected question is about Caffe not keras. I don't think this is a completely duplicate question.

Comment: you can broadcast just the weights of the model and use `pandas_udf` where you build the model and load the weights

Comment: @zero323 can you explain why the question is duplicated? and how to use the solution to keras?